# Vue 3 Typescript not assignable to type ‘[]‘

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to set the type of my array in my data properties like this:

```
const Projects = defineComponent({
  data: () => ({
    issues: [] as IssueType[]
  }),
```

I am calling this method which filters the array:

```
getIssues(projectId: number, label: string): [] {
  return this.issues.filter(
    issue => issue.project_id === projectId && issue.labels?.includes(label)
  );
```

But Typescript returns me following error:

```
> Type 'IssueType[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.   Types of property
> 'length' are incompatible.
>     Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, the type `[]` explicitly mean empty array/tuple.

```
type A = [];

const a: A = ['a'];
// Error -> Type '[string]' is not assignable to type '[]'

const a: A = [];
// No error

export default a;
```

Therefore, what you need to do is just explicitly set the return type with `IssueType[]` instead of `[]`.

Comment: If I do this `data: () => ({
    issues: IssueType = []
  }),` I get following error `'IssueType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: @kimfs you dont have to do that, you are already correct doing `data: () => ({ issues: [] as IssueType[] })`. The part that you need to change is the `getIssues(projectId: number, label: string): IssueType[]`